# First Minecraft mod not working: make a new sword

Tags: java, minecraft-modding, modding

I am making my first mod and cannot see what is wrong with it. I am using MCP and Modloader.
For my first mod I was going to make swords.

I started with making a new `EnumToolMaterials`

```
WOOD(0, 59, 2.0F, 0, 15),
STONE(1, 131, 4.0F, 1, 5),
IRON(2, 250, 6.0F, 2, 14),
LAPIS(3, 750, 7.0F, 2, 14),
OBSIDIAN(3, 1000, 7.5F, 3, 12),
EMERALD(3, 1561, 8.0F, 3, 10),//diamond
GREEN(3, 2000, 9.0F, 4, 10),//emerald
GOLD(0, 200, 12.0F, 0, 22);
```

then here is the mod class

```
public class _Mod_Yamiko extends BaseMod{

    /* mod itemts */
    public static final Item swordLapis = (new ItemSword(600, EnumToolMaterial.LAPIS)).setItemName("swordLapis");
    public static final Item swordObsidian = (new ItemSword(601, EnumToolMaterial.OBSIDIAN)).setItemName("swordObsidian");
    public static final Item swordGreen = (new ItemSword(602, EnumToolMaterial.GREEN)).setItemName("swordGreen");

    public void load(){
        //set images
        swordLapis.iconIndex = ModLoader.addOverride("/gui/items.png","/gui/swordLapis.png");

        ModLoader.addName(swordLapis, "Lapis Sword");
        //craft
        ModLoader.addRecipe(new ItemStack(_Mod_Yamiko.swordLapis, 1), new Object[]{
            " X ", " X ", " Y ",
            'X', Block.dirt, 
            'Y', Item.stick 
        });
    }

    public String getVersion(){
        return "0.1";
    }
}
```

Then I made a 16×16 .png image. I am not sure where to save it so I recompiled and reobfuscated, took the mod files and put it in my local Minecraft install, added the image where it be should be. No problems when playing but I cannot make the new sword.

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
ModLoader.addRecipe(new ItemStack(_Mod_Yamiko.swordLapis, 1), new Object[]{
            " X ", " X ", " Y ",
            Character.valueOf("X"), Block.dirt, 
            Character.valueOf("Y"), Item.stick 
        });
```

when referencing the characters

Comment: You mean `Character.valueOf('X')` with single quotes, right?  Although I'm a bit surprised (having not worked with Java much lately) that just using a primitive char literal in an Object array doesn't simply autobox it.